# MYSQL How to match two words in a sentence

Tags: mysql, regex, database

I have a table with column mytext which contains sentences.

I want to search sentences which are having two words like  "my" "school" in any order.

**What i want as result is**

1. oxford is my school
2. my name is kk school is jes

etc.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mytext REGEXP "school|my";` might work.

Comment: Hi Thanks for help
It is returning sentences have either "school" or "my"

not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB tables(and you probably are), you can use LIKE statement:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE "%my%" 
                         OR mycolumn LIKE "%school%";`

For fulltext search much better solution would be using dedicated search engine, optimized for such purposes - for example [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/).

Comment: Thanks Query is Approx what i want

Answer (score 2):

The query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mycolumn LIKE "%my%" 
and mycolumn LIKE "%school%";
```

will return also sentences like:

- "mysql school"
- "my oldschool parents"

But we do not want them.

You can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mycolumn regexp ' my |^my | my$'
and mycolumn regexp ' school |^school | school$'
```

But if in the column mycolumn you have sentences like:

- I love my school!

you should think about adding another condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE mycolumn regexp ' my |^my | my$'
and mycolumn regexp '[^a-zA-Z]school[^a-zA-Z]|^school | school$'
```

Comment: Thanks for regexp solution!

Answer (score 1):

You could use

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE mycolumn REGEXP '(?=.*\bmy\b)(?=.*\bschool\b)';`

`(?=` it is a positive lookahead. It matches the pattern without consume characters
`.*` matches any number of any characters
`\b` matches a word boundary

[You can read more about this here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pcre/)
[and here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

This is a nice approach because you can add new words just adding more positive lookaheads, like this:

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE mycolumn REGEXP '(?=.*\bmy\b)(?=.*\bspecial\b)(?=.*\bschool\b)';`

(To test it in some apps, like HeidiSQL, can be necessary to escape \ using \)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FULLTEXT search.

Full text searches are based on FULLTEXT indexes, which may be created only for MyISAM tables, and only for TEXT columns and non-BINARY CHAR and VARCHAR columns.

FULLTEXT searches are not case sensitive. This follows as a consequence of the column types for which FULLTEXT indexes may be used.

In your case :

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(mycolumn) AGAINST('my school');

Comment: Hi Thanks 
I tried it but it will not return the sentence 
"my name is kk school is jes"